# Simple Camel Transformation

Tags: apache-camel

I've just managed to run my first Camel route (from timer to a JMS queue):

```
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("timer:foo?period=1s").setBody(body().
                    append("Message at ${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}")).to(
                            "jms:queue:activemq/queue/TestQueue");
                }
            });
```

However I just realized that the following JMS message is received:

```
nullMessage at ${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}
```

Is there something missing to enable the variable substitution so that I get the real date in the message ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timer has a `null` body, so `body().append()` would do a `null` + whatever.

So instead of append, just set the body. And use the simple language, if you want the timestamp to be computed.

```
.setBody(simple("Message at ${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}"))
```